# Moving tasks from current to past sprint in rally

Tags: rally

There were some tasks in previous sprint that I did not close. After this sprint day started, then only I closed one task and updated actuals in other two tasks. Few days later I found that those tasks were moved from previous sprint to this sprint resulting in anomaly. The expected hours shot up for this sprint while same amount is less in previous sprint. I dont know if I should really be asking this here. Still, how do I fix the situation without deleting from current sprint and recreating them in previous sprint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you probably should have split the story at the iteration boundary, leaving the completed tasks on the story in the last iteration and moving the uncompleted tasks to the new story in the current iteration.

As for now I think you'll probably want to simulate that by doing what you said.